# Arrayformula relative cell reference formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need a relative cell reference formula that works in a Sheets Arrayformula.
The pseudocode for a col of dynamic data is:  Arrayformula (If  'cell 10 rows to the left'  ="Yes", "sentence"," ")
I'd be most grateful for help with the Sheets relative reference formula.  Peter

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can effectively help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was looking at relative references is because this is a Google Forms Response sheet. Under Appscript control the linked Response sheet is cleared for the start of new data. But the Arrayformula pointers would then reset themselves to a different row and are no longer referencing the intended row. So I thought this might be a workaround.

I've since made what to me is a startling discovery.  When I deleteRows() in the Response sheet starting with Row 3 [ "deleteRow(3,150)" ] leaving Row 2 to stay blank, then the next G Forms data comes in at Row 3 with the arrayformula pointers still accurate!!  Who Knew!!   Thanks all.